# How to add threads every second in load testing using JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

Hi guys im newbee in JMeter. My load testing needs to test 200 users in 1hr only. But I want to start in 20 users only and add 20 users every 360 seconds until reach 200 users after 1 hr. How to do that in thread group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be using [Stepping Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SteppingThreadGroup/) with the configuration like:

[image: JMeter Stepping Thread Group Example]

You can install Stepping Thread Group as a part of `Custom Thread Groups` bundle using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image: JMeter Custom Thread Groups]